# Does UnityScript support Object Literal syntax?

Tags: monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I hear that UnityScript is pretty close to JavaScript. Does UnityScript support the Object Literal syntax of JavaScript?

e.g.

```
var x = {
    y: 12
};
```

Strangely, searching google for `UnityScript "Object Literal"` yields no useful results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UnityScript versus JavaScript](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) have very different semantics.

Creating a new JavaScript file in Unity with this syntax will not compile.

```
#pragma strict

var x = {
    y: 12 // error: BCE0005
};

function Start () {
   Debug.Log (x.y); // error: BCE0019
}
```

This will give build errors:

> NewBehaviourScript(4,5): BCE0005: unknown identifier: 'y'.
>   NewBehaviourScript(8,17): BCE0019: 'y' is not a member of 'Boo.Lang.Hash'.

However, you could implement a `Hashtable`:

```
#pragma strict

var x:Hashtable = new Hashtable();
x["y"] = 12;

function Start () {
   Debug.Log (x["y"]);
}
```

Comment: Weird that that wiki page doesn't even mention lack of object literal support (since that's one of JS most useful features).  I tried to create an account to raise this point, but the site requires you to enter a min 50 word biography just to register!